# Проблемы с AttributeSet

Tags: java, android, android-view

Не могу понять, как запустить `SurfaceView` с другого класса, так как в нем есть `AttributeSet`. Как его получить?

```
class PongGame extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    private GameThread _thread;

    public PongGame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        //So we can listen for events...
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        //and instantiate the thread
        _thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
        return _thread.getGameState().keyPressed(keyCode, msg);
    }

    //Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        //Mandatory, just swallowing it for this example

    }

    //Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.start();
    }

    //Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _thread.stop();
    }
}
```

Cама View. Как его запустить в классе `PongStart`?

```
public class PongStart extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //тут должно что-то быть
        setContentView(new  PongGame(this,  attr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Передайте `null`: `new PongGame(this,  null)`

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeSet attrs` в конструкторе у классов, унаследованных от `View`, используется системой, если вы создаёте этот класс в разметке xml лейаута. Туда попадают различные атрибуты из xml. Так как вы создаёте свою вью программно, то вместо атрибутов нужно передать `null`:

```
setContentView(new PongGame(this, null));
```